# How would I cite a statistical report put out by a company in MLA?

Tags: citations

I would like to cite [MPAA-Theatrical-Market-Statistics-2016](https://www.mpaa.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/MPAA-Theatrical-Market-Statistics-2016_Final.pdf) in MLA. Is it one of the following?

```
Book*
Digital Image
Film / Online Video*
Journal Article*
Online Database
Website*
Other
Write / paste citation
All Sources
Advertisement
Bible*
Blog / Podcast
Book*
Brochure
Cartoon / Comic
Chapter / Anthology*
Collection Article
Conference Proceedings*
Congressional Publication*
Court Case
Dictionary Entry*
Digital File
Digital Image
Dissertation*
Dissertation (abstract)*
E-mail
Editorial
Encyclopedia Article*
Executive Order
Federal Bill*
Federal Report
Federal Rule
Federal Statute
Federal Testimony
Film / Online Video*
Government Publication*
Interview
Journal Article*
Lecture / Speech
Letter
Live Performance
Magazine Article*
Mailing List
Manuscript
Map / Chart*
Microform
Miscellaneous
Multivolume Work*
Music / Audio*
Newsgroup
Newsletter
Newspaper Article*
Online Database
Painting / Artwork
Pamphlet
Patent
Photograph
Preface / Foreword*
Press Release
Raw Data
Report
Reprinted Work
Review
Scholarly Project
Software*
Television / Radio
Thesis*
Website
```

Comment: Downvoted for being too lazy to exclude options that clearly do not fit.

Comment: There is a mistake in Boondoggle's answer: The PDF file of the *Theatrical Market Statistics* report is ***not*** a website! The examples given in the answer even contradict that assertion: The first example shows a link to a PDF file and names it a "report *on* a website" (my emphasis). The second example shows a link to an htm(l)-webpage and names it a "web page". Clearly the report in question is a report on a website and not a website.

Comment: Welcome to Writing. Please have a look at our site [tour] and [help] pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a report.

It even says so on page 3:

> "As the 2016 Theatrical Market Statistics **Report** confirms, yet again, movies continue to play a vital
>   role in our lives and our cultures. Around the world, storytelling – and the movie-going experience
>   that brings great stories to life – is very much alive and well."

It's also a website.  An MLA formatting style guide can be found on [mtroyal.ca](http://www.mtroyal.ca/library/files/citation/mla_research.pdf). The `http://` prefix at the start of the URL has to be dropped.

Because there is a publication date in the URL you could cite it like this:

> *Theatrical market statistics 2016. Motion Picture Association of America*, Mar. 2017, www.mpaa.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/MPAA-Theatrical-Market-Statistics-2016_Final.pdf.

Source: [mtroyal D3](http://www.mtroyal.ca/library/files/citation/mla_research.pdf):

[image: mtroyal MLA style D3]

---

When there is no publication date you could cite it like this:

> "Theatrical market statistics 2016." *Motion Picture Association of America*, www.mpaa.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/MPAA-Theatrical-Market-Statistics-2016_Final.pdf. Accessed 24 Jan. 2018.

Source: [mtroyal D2](http://www.mtroyal.ca/library/files/citation/mla_research.pdf)

[image: mtroyal MLA style D2]

Answer (score 1):

Please learn how to use the internet to find information.

1. If you had taken the moment to delete all the options that clearly do not fit (it is not a film, not published by the government ["federal"], not a court case, not software, etc.), you would have been left with the following three options:

   - Other
   - Miscellaneous
   - Report
2. If you had done the obvious and tried to find some information on this publication, for example through an internet search, you would have read the phrase "Theatrical Market Statistics report" over and over in different sources.
3. If you had done your job and *read* the publication, you would have been told that it is a report (see the answer by Boondoggle).
4. If you had looked at where the publication is published, you would have read the website title "Research & Reports".